# How to fill Rad combo by image in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox, radgrid

so i have two question

the first one is:

i had folder in my project several image i name them from 1-10.png

what i want to do  is to fill my rad combo by image in that folder can i ??

second one:

how can i put combo box in rad combo box i tried so mush and its seem nothing work .

This is my radGrid:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gvServices1" HorizontalAlign ="Center"  AllowMultiRowSelection="True"
                runat="server" 
                AllowSorting="True"
                CellSpacing="0" Width="90%" GridLines="None" meta:resourcekey="gvUnitResource1">
             <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ServiceId" 
                    Width="100%">

                    <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF" />
                    <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column" Visible="True">
                    </RowIndicatorColumn>
                    <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column" Visible="True">
                    </ExpandCollapseColumn>

                    <Columns>



                                     <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ServiceId" DataType="System.Int32" HeaderText="Number"
                           ReadOnly="True" UniqueName="ServiceId" AllowFiltering="False"  Visible="False"
                            meta:resourcekey="IDResource1" FilterControlAltText="Filter ServiceId column">
                         <HeaderStyle Width="10px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>


                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ServiceName_EN" HeaderText="ServiceName_EN"
                           ReadOnly="True" UniqueName="ServiceName_EN" AllowFiltering="False"
                            meta:resourcekey="ServiceName_ENResource1" FilterControlAltText="Filter ServiceName_EN column">
                         <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>


                          <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SPath" HeaderText="SPath"
                           ReadOnly="True" UniqueName="SPath" AllowFiltering="False"  Visible="False"
                            meta:resourcekey="IDResource1" FilterControlAltText="Filter SPath column">
                         <HeaderStyle Width="50px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="ClientSelectColumn" HeaderText="Fav" FilterControlAltText="Filter ClientSelectColumn column" meta:resourcekey="GridClientSelectColumnResource1">
                </telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>

                    </Columns>

                    <EditFormSettings>
                        <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
                        </EditColumn>

                    </EditFormSettings>

                    <BatchEditingSettings EditType="Cell" />
                    <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="True" PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" />




                </MasterTableView>
             <ExportSettings>
                 <Pdf>
                     <PageHeader>
                         <LeftCell Text="" />
                         <MiddleCell Text="" />
                         <RightCell Text="" />
                     </PageHeader>
                     <PageFooter>
                         <LeftCell Text="" />
                         <MiddleCell Text="" />
                         <RightCell Text="" />
                     </PageFooter>
                 </Pdf>
             </ExportSettings>
             <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="True" >
            <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" UseClientSelectColumnOnly="true"></Selecting>
                     <Scrolling UseStaticHeaders="True" />
                     </ClientSettings> 
                <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="False" />

             <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="True" PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" />
             <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
             </FilterMenu>

            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding images to `RadComboBox`

```
<telerik:radcombobox 
id="RadComboBox3" 
runat="server" 
skin="Outlook" 
allowcustomtext="true">    
<Items>        
    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem ImageUrl="Img/ComboboxPr.gif" Text="RadComboBox" runat="server">        
    </telerik:RadComboBoxItem>        
    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem ImageUrl="Img/MenuPr.gif" Text="RadMenu" runat="server">        
    </telerik:RadComboBoxItem>        
    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem ImageUrl="Img/TreeviewPr.gif" Text="RadTreeView" runat="server">        
    </telerik:RadComboBoxItem>        
    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem ImageUrl="Img/SchedulerPr.gif" Text="RadScheduler">        
    </telerik:RadComboBoxItem>        
    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem ImageUrl="Img/UploadPr.gif" Text="RadUpload">        
    </telerik:RadComboBoxItem>    
</Items>
</telerik:radcombobox>
```

[try this example](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/radcombobox-items/custom-attributes)